# Find model records against Time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model with 2 specific fields named *start* and *end*.
Those are dates I want to check against current date ( Time.now ) in order to get only records where current time is comprised between *start* and *end* stored values

I tried a few things such as

```
Model.all.find_by(start: <Time.now , end: >Time.now)
```

But I get syntax errors all the time. Sometimes the field name of the second date ( *end* ) is even mixed up with the 'end' keyword inside my controller.

Comment: First thing you need to do is change the name of your end column to finish or end_dt or something other than end. Madness will be your reality if you continue to use end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Model.where('start < ? and end > ?', Time.now, Time.now)
```

By the way, `all` is redundant in this situation.

Comment: using find_by actually returns a funny error: 'undefinded method each..' inside my view file. But Model.where('start < ? and end > ?', Time.now, Time.now) seems to work perfectly ! Thanks

Comment: @Maxence: `find_by` returns a single object, while `where` returns a collection.